# after open a page in react js pwa app the height changed and is smaller than before

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

when I open a page in pwa in IOS with window.location.assign, the app height change and is smaller than before. even I close the opened page its height is not full.

window.innerHeight before open page is 647.
window.innerHeight before open page is 559.

how can i make these two height equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `viewport-fit=cover` in the header, and its ok now.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" />
```

Comment: I used this but there is a problem. in this case we have extra space on the bottom. This problem is on the ios.